# 2006 Chevy Avalanche Radio Fuse Location

Tags: chevrolet, fuse, avalanche

Where is the radio fuse in a 2006 Avalanche.

The manual is below.

http://chevyavalancheclub.com/index.php?board=266.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the underhood fuse panel, located here:

[image]